# Excel Method to flag none completed course from exported training system data

Tags: microsoft-excel

So i have a data export

[image: Example of Data Export]

And im trying to work out a way to flag when a user by email has not completed a training course. So what I'm trying to achieve is as an output like below

[image: example of wanted output]

I have been reading and trying a few things like a `COUNTIF`, `INDEX` but i just can't work it out.

CSV of images:

```
First Name,Last Name,User's Email,Team,Course name,Completion status,Progress (% complete),
Name 1,Lname 1,Name 1.Lname 1@hidden.tdl,HR,basic first aid,Complete via rpl,100,
Name 2,Lname 2,Name 2.Lname 2@hidden.tdl,Technology,basic first aid,Completed,100,
Name 3,Lname 3,Name 3.Lname 3@hidden.tdl,Technology,basic first aid,Not started,0,
Name 4,Lname 4,Name 4.Lname 4@hidden.tdl,Technology,basic first aid,Completed,100,
Name 5,Lname 5,Name 5.Lname 5@hidden.tdl,Technology,basic first aid,In progress,0,
Name 6,Lname 6,Name 6.Lname 6@hidden.tdl,Network,basic first aid,Completed,100,
Name 7,Lname 7,Name 7.Lname 7@hidden.tdl,Technology,basic first aid,Completed,100,
Name 8,Lname 8,Name 8.Lname 8@hidden.tdl,Marketing,basic first aid,Completed,100,
Name 9,Lname 9,Name 9.Lname 9@hidden.tdl,Technology,basic first aid,Not started,0,
Name 6,Lname 6,Name 6.Lname 6@hidden.tdl,Network,becoming a manager,Completed,100,
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
First Name,Last Name,User's Email,Basic First Aid,becoming a manager,,,
Name 1,Lname 1,Name 1.Lname 1@hidden.tdl,TRUE,FALSE,,,
Name 2,Lname 2,Name 2.Lname 2@hidden.tdl,TRUE,FALSE,,,
Name 3,Lname 3,Name 3.Lname 3@hidden.tdl,FALSE,FALSE,,,
Name 4,Lname 4,Name 4.Lname 4@hidden.tdl,TRUE,FALSE,,,
Name 5,Lname 5,Name 5.Lname 5@hidden.tdl,FALSE,FALSE,,,
Name 6,Lname 6,Name 6.Lname 6@hidden.tdl,TRUE,TRUE,,,
Name 7,Lname 7,Name 7.Lname 7@hidden.tdl,TRUE,FALSE,,,
Name 8,Lname 8,Name 8.Lname 8@hidden.tdl,TRUE,FALSE,,,
Name 9,Lname 9,Name 9.Lname 9@hidden.tdl,FALSE,FALSE,,,
```

Comment: If completion status or progress can be used as a proxy for your true/false, then a pivot table would get to your output

Comment: Use a PivotTable and Sum the Completion percentages. Use a custom number format to show "True" for values >=1 and "False" for all others. Or get creative and show "Complete" and Not complete". Or add a third category for >0.5 as "In Progress"